# An inequality involving $k$-generalized Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

I have worked on a Diophantine equation by using transcendental and reduction methods given by Baker and Davenport. However, to solve completely the equation I have one complicated case and I proved that for this case it is enough to prove the following inequality
$$
F_{2m-2}^{(k)}<(F_m^{(k)})^2+1,
$$
for all $m\geq 1$ and $k\geq 3$ (or $m>k+1$).

Here, $(F_m^{(k)})_{m\geq -(k-2)}$ is defined by the recurrence
$$
F_m^{(k)}=F_{m-1}^{(k)}+F_{m-2}^{(k)}+\cdots + F_{m-k}^{(k)},
$$
with initial values $0,0,\ldots, 0,1=F_1^{(k)}$ ($k-1$ zeroes).

Any suggestion could be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For large values of $m$ and $k$, Theorem 2 in ["A Simplified Binet Formula for k-Generalized Fibonacci Numbers"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0304) should work. Things may get grody for small values.

Answer (score 8):

$F_{\ell+1}$ is just the number of ways to tile an interval of length $\ell$ by tiles of lengths up to $k$. Now take the interval of length $2m-3$ and look at what happens at the mark $m-2$. You may have it as a boundary point, which gives you $F_{m-1}F_m$ configurations or you may have it splitting one of the intervals into two subintervals with the left one of length $a\in\{1,\dots,k-1\}$ , which gives you at most $F_{m-1-a}F_{m}$ configurations. Thus, the total number of configurations is at most $\left[\sum_{a=0}^{k-1}F_{m-1-a}\right]F_m=F_m^2$, so, indeed, $F_{2m-2}\le F_m^2$.